# Two sets of parentheses inside an if statement, what does that mean?

Tags: javascript

Recently I saw some weird code that looks kinda like this:

```
let a;
if ((a = anotherVariable)) {
 ....
}
```

Can you explain to me what does this mean and why is it done?

Edit:

Notice that he's not comparing `a` to `anotherVariable`, he's assigning it. And there are no other terms in the if parentheses, so it's not like `if ((something) && (something else)) {...}`.

So why not just assign `a` variable separately, and then check for truthiness of `anotherVariable`?

Original code [here](https://github.com/letterpad/letterpad/blob/92cc3147512ab6f34c8bf66c2ad780d6afdb7727/admin/features/article/editor/plugins/markdown/MarkdownUtils.js) (search for `matched = prevTextFromSpace`).

Comment: Just an added level of grouping, this doesn’t change anything in that simple example.

Comment: @misorude Notice that he's not comparing a to anotherVariable, there's only one = sign, he's assigning it.

Comment: this will add parentheses to expression where value of  `anotherVariable` is assinged to `a`.

Comment: @RayAlez yes, but that doesn’t change anything either. Result is the same with or without that set of additional braces.

Comment: The extra parens are to shut up the linter.

Comment: @georg Aha, this sounds like it could be the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write

```
if (a = anotherVariable) {
 ....
}
```

it works fine but `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.

The value of the expression `a = b` is the value of `b` (and it is also stored in the variable `a`). If `b` evaluates to a truish value then the `if` branch is taken.

However, because `=` is not `==`, the linter programs usually flag an `if` statement as above as a potential error. It happens many times that the developer wanted `==` and typed `=` by mistake. The linters try to detect this error.

If the real intention is to copy the value of `b` in  `a` and also use this value as the condition of the `if` statement (and not to compare `a` to `b`) then the code above is correct. There are two ways to silent the linter warning:

1. Put the assignment in front of the `if` statement:

   ```
   a = b
   if (a) {
      ...
   }
   ```
2. Put the assignment inside a pair of parentheses:

   ```
   if ((a = b)) {
      ...
   }
   ```

   This decouples the assignment from the `if`. The assignment is not the `if` condition any more.
   The assignment is just a sub-expression of the larger expression `(a = b)`.

   This larger expression is the condition of the `if` statement and it is not an assignment, so there is nothing to warn about. Yes, it contains an assignment but the assignment is just a sub-expression.

It looks like a hack but it is not. It only denotes a good understanding of expressions and statements in programming languages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this explains it!

Answer (score 1):

The inner parenthesis simply evaluates the expression it contains. It will assign the value of *anotherVariable* to the variable *a* and that new value will be compared with the other operand in the condition.

```js
let a = 2, anotherVariable=20;
if ((a = anotherVariable) == 20) {
 console.log(a)
}
```

Comment: So does this always evaluate to true (always making the `if` body execute)?

Comment: @NickParsons, in the above example yes....if a is falsy it will not execute the code...

Comment: @Mamun Thank you! I have updated the question with link to original code, for context. I'm trying to figure out what's the purpose of writing it like this. Did the author want to assign the variable and check truthiness of anotherVariable at the same time?

Comment: *"It will assign the value of anotherVariable to the variable a and that new value will be evaluated as the condition."* -- that's exactly how it works without the extra set of parentheses too.

Comment: @axiac, if there is another operand in the condition like `if ((a = anotherVariable) == 20) `, then `if (a = anotherVariable == 20) ` will not give you the expected output....

Comment: @Mamun *"if there is another operand in the condition"* -- there is no other operator in the condition. It is just `a = b` vs `(a = b)`. And the parentheses do not do what you claim.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually do anything except group the components. Let's say it looked like this:

```
if (a && (b || c))
```

Here, the parentheses would matter, because without them, JavaScript would interpret them incorrectly IIRC, as it'd look like this:

```
if (a && b || c)
```

And it's hard to tell what that'd output. Grouping is also important when you're using multiple ternary operators, like this:

```
if ((a : b ? c) && (d : g ? f))
```

Here, the parentheses are extremely important - bit of an extreme example, I know, but it illustrates my point nicely.

In short, parentheses grouping is a good habit to get into in JavaScript, as even when you have extremely simple conditions like:

```
if ((a > b) && (c < d))
```

It's very easy to get confused when you are meant to have two or more layers of parentheses. Imagine thinking through this with no parentheses!

```
if ((((a ? b : c) == (d < e)) && (f !== g)) || !(h == j))
```

Hopefully this helps!